# @set in backbone.js working for one attribute but not another

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

TL;DR of UPDATE:  It was a missing attr_accessible.

I just started with backbone.js, and I'm trying to expand Ryan Bates' [raffler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/325-backbone-on-rails-part-2) into a todo list.

Right now, I'm trying to get it to save when an item has been "completed".  To ensure that it is in a working branch of code, I put the @set in with a @set that I knew was working.

```
win: ->
    @set(winner: true)
    @set(completed: true)
    @save()
```

The 'completed' attribute shows up as true, but goes back to false when I reset the page.  The 'winner' attribute stays true.

Here's my view code (.jst.echo format):

```
<span class="entry">
<% if @entry.get('completed'): %>
  <input class='is-done' type='checkbox'  checked />
<% else: %>
  <input class='is-done' type='checkbox'  />
<% end %>
<%= @entry.get('name') %>
<%= @entry.score() %>

<% if @entry.get('winner'): %>
  <span class="winner">WINNER</span>
<% end %>
</span>
```

And here's my rails database schema:

```
create_table "entries", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.boolean  "winner"
  t.datetime "created_at",                    :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                    :null => false
  t.boolean  "completed",  :default => false
end
```

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:  SOLVED

The problem was that I had not set 'completed' as attr_accessible.  Note in the following Put statement that while 'completed' is returned at true, only 'name' and 'winner' are in the 'entries' hash.

```
Started PUT "/api/entries/2" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by EntriesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"entry"=>{"name"=>"There", "winner"=>true}, "completed"=>true, "created_at"=>"2012-04-16T18:04:41Z", "id"=>"2", "name"=>"There", "updated_at"=>"2012-04-16T18:13:04Z", "winner"=>true}
```

After setting 'completed' to attr_accessible, it gives the following:

```
Started PUT "/api/entries/2" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by EntriesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"entry"=>{"name"=>"There", "winner"=>true, **"complete"=>true**}, "completed"=>true, "created_at"=>"2012-04-16T18:04:41Z", "id"=>"2", "name"=>"There", "updated_at"=>"2012-04-16T18:13:04Z", "winner"=>true}
```

And more importantly, it works.

Comment: are you sure your object is saving back up to rails? The default value for the 'completed' boolean is false, could that be why that option is coming back false?

Comment: It wasn't because of the default, but you got me thinking more deeply about what was going on in rails.  I updated the question with what I figured out.